# Update eclipse from galileo to helios on kubuntu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt, helios, galileo, ubuntu

I installed eclipse galileo from kubuntu package manager. For some reason, there is no helios available yet. Then I tried to manually install helios, but when I run it, I get message: "The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library."

Then I opened galileo, and installed PDT from helio update site. But due to some galileo - helios incompatability, I get error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wst/css/ui/internal/contentassist/CSSStructuredContentAssistProcessor

when I try to open PHP file.

I read on http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_update_Eclipse%3F that I can update to helios if I add helios update site in Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites, which I tried, but when i run "check for updates" it says that there is nothing to update.

Any idea how to get helios PDT installed on kubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you download the Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers package from here:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Make sure that you get one that's correct for your OS and pay particular attention to 32/64 bit variation. You have to match 32/64 bitness of Eclipse with 32/64 bitness of your JVM. Run "java -version" to see the type of JVM that you have. If you don't match these up, Eclipse will not start with a message like the one you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, that fixed my problem. I have downloaded it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliossr2 and it worked like a charm. I wonder why one from http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/ didn't. What is the difference between this two?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having problems with eclipse Helios on Kubuntu or Ubuntu, I would suggest you remove your current installation and follow the [instructions](http://brohaveyouseenmysocks.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/how-to-install-eclipse-sdk-3-6-2-helios-with-subclipse-and-the-marketplace-client/) I just posted on my blog after *finally* getting 3.6.2 working with both the Marketplace Client and Subclipse. I just tried posting the whole entry here but it wouldn't allow the number of hyperlinks required to get the install working.